Is there a way to code CSV or XML into Mapbox from database?
Aviation weather website produces the two files that are linked at the bottom and constantly updates them every minute. I am not able to manage the files 24/7 as they do and would like to find a way to code some sort of addSource to my Mapbox map to pull the information from the website link.
The closest I have found is Mapbox's geojson, which I have pasted below. This hasn't done me much good as I need to pull lat and long from a CSV/XML file from a website address and I am at a loss. All I can find on Google is how to convert CSV to geoJSON to upload to mapbox and have a static layer that will not update automatically. Any point in the right direction would be much appreciated.
https://aviationweather.gov/data/cache/metars.cache.csv
https://aviationweather.gov/data/cache/metars.cache.xml
Here is the provided geoJSON code from Mapbox:
map.on('load', () => {
        map.addSource('earthquakes', {
            type: 'geoJSON',
            // Use a URL for the value for the `data` property.
            data: 'https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/earthquakes.geojson'
        });

        map.addLayer({
            'id': 'earthquakes-layer',
            'type': 'circle',
            'source': 'earthquakes',
            'paint': {
                'circle-radius': 4,
                'circle-stroke-width': 2,
                'circle-color': 'red',
                'circle-stroke-color': 'white'
            }
  
        });
    });

I have tried
type: 'csv',
data: 'https://aviationweather.gov/data/cache/metars.cache.csv'
As well as 'xml' and '.xml' neither of them did anything for me as I may be missing the lat long request in the addLayer portion of the code.

Try: https://github.com/mapbox/csv2geojson?tab=readme-ov-file
Just convert CSV to GeoJSON and load it with "addSource".

I made a small test with your data from the CSV file, and it works perfectly.


const myCsvString = `raw_text,station_id,observation_time,latitude,longitude,temp_c,dewpoint_c,wind_dir_degrees,wind_speed_kt,wind_gust_kt,visibility_statute_mi,altim_in_hg,sea_level_pressure_mb,corrected,auto,auto_station,maintenance_indicator_on,no_signal,lightning_sensor_off,freezing_rain_sensor_off,present_weather_sensor_off,wx_string,sky_cover,cloud_base_ft_agl,sky_cover,cloud_base_ft_agl,sky_cover,cloud_base_ft_agl,sky_cover,cloud_base_ft_agl,flight_category,three_hr_pressure_tendency_mb,maxT_c,minT_c,maxT24hr_c,minT24hr_c,precip_in,pcp3hr_in,pcp6hr_in,pcp24hr_in,snow_in,vert_vis_ft,metar_type,elevation_m
PKWA 220920Z AUTO 00000KT 10SM CLR 28/24 A2983 RMK AO2 T02760240,PKWA,2024-10-22T09:20:00Z,8.72,167.724,27.6,24,0,0,,10+,29.83,,,TRUE,TRUE,,,,,,,CLR,,,,,,,,VFR,,,,,,,,,,,,METAR,6
LWSK 220920Z VRB02KT CAVOK 15/08 Q1032 NOSIG,LWSK,2024-10-22T09:20:00Z,41.952,21.627,15,8,VRB,2,,6+,30.47,,,,,,TRUE,,,,,CAVOK,,,,,,,,VFR,,,,,,,,,,,,METAR,232
LWOH 220920Z 16006KT 9999 FEW035 15/10 Q1031,LWOH,2024-10-22T09:20:00Z,41.181,20.744,15,10,160,6,,6+,30.44,,,,,,,,,,,FEW,3500,,,,,,,VFR,,,,,,,,,,,,METAR,700
LLBG 220920Z 35009KT CAVOK 26/07 Q1017 NOSIG RMK FEW055,LLBG,2024-10-22T09:20:00Z,32.011,34.887,26,7,350,9,,6+,30.03,,,,,,TRUE,,,,,CAVOK,,,,,,,,VFR,,,,,,,,,,,,METAR,35
LATI 220920Z VRB02KT CAVOK 21/10 Q1028 NOSIG,LATI,2024-10-22T09:20:00Z,41.419,19.716,21,10,VRB,2,,6+,30.35,,,,,,TRUE,,,,,CAVOK,,,,,,,,VFR,,,,,,,,,,,,METAR,32`;

csv2geojson.csv2geojson(myCsvString, {
    latfield: 'latitude', //name of column with latitude
    lonfield: 'longitude', //name of column with longitude
    delimiter: ','
}, function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);
});
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>csv2json</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/csv2geojson@latest/csv2geojson.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
  </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>



Of course, you need to load your CSV data from the file, but it is also possible. Don't forget about CORS "problem".
Should not be a problem via jQuery, for example: $.load or $.get or JavaScript fetch().
